# How do I get standardized beta coefficients using modelsummary in R? And how to omit more than one variable using modelsummary?

Tags: r, modelsummary

I am using modelsummary to create a table. I would like to the estimate (regression coefficients) to be standardized. I used lm.beta() but the estimate = is giving me the non-standardized coefficient. Also, I would like to use coef.omitt to take out more than one variable. How might I do this?

Answer (score 2):

This solution only works using the development version of `modelsummary`. This version should be on CRAN in the next few weeks, but you can install it now:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Under the hood, `modelsummary` uses the `parameters` package to extract parameters from model objects. [As you can see here](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/model_parameters.html#standardization-of-model-coefficients), that package can apply several different kinds of standardization. You can pass a `standardize` argument directly to `modelsummary()`, which will then pass it down to `parameters`.

The `coef_omit` argument accepts regular expressions. [See the documentation to learn how to omit several coefficients.](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html#coef_omit) ex: `coef_omit="x|y|z"`

For example:

```r
library(modelsummary)
mod <- lm(mpg ~ hp + factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
modelsummary(mod, standardize = "basic")
```

|  | Model 1 |
| --- | --- |
| (Intercept) | 0.000 |
|  | (0.000) |
| hp | -0.273 |
|  | (0.175) |
| factor(cyl)6 | -0.416 |
|  | (0.114) |
| factor(cyl)8 | -0.713 |
|  | (0.195) |
| Num.Obs. | 32 |
| R2 | 0.754 |
| R2 Adj. | 0.727 |
| AIC | 169.9 |
| BIC | 177.2 |
| F | 28.585 |
| RMSE | 2.94 |

Comment: Thank you! I ran the code with standardize = "basic" but did not seem to get the standardized coefficients. There was no error though - just brings in the unstandardized coefficients.

Comment: Did you install the development version and restart `R` before trying?

Comment: As in hrl's case, modelsummary with standardize="basic" works for the mtcars example but just shows unstandardized coefficients for my data using feols. My modelsummary version is 1.1.0.9000. Interesting that easystats only works with "refit" method and throws errors with all others.

Comment: Maybe `parameters:: parameters` does not support `fixest` models for standardization?